# Ported Functions Licensing

Tags: c++, python, documentation, licensing, porting

I have found several functions in python 2.7.2 to be very useful and I recreated them in C++ for my own uses. How do I properly give python credit for them? Do I even have to? I never actually looked at their source codes. I just wrote functions that output the same values as the python versions of the function.

Comment: As a sidenote, you might be interested in [nuitka](http://www.nuitka.net/), which translates Python code to C++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to give any credit if you don't want to.

Most computer languages are inspired by other languages and have features like those languages. Just check Python's own [tutorial on classes](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) and [library reference for itertools](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html). While reading these I thought they were advertising and nearly gave up reading the tutorial on classes as it was too much in the beginning.

The point is that if you want you can mention that in a comment or fill paragraphs about how you were inspired by Python but it is not necessary as you never used/saw their actual code.